Does there exist an oriented graph with fixed amount of vertices and fixed possible indegree and outdegree?
I am considering an oriented graph without loops and multiple edges. The question is:
Does there exist an oriented graph with $100$ vertices, where the indegrees of vertices is either $2$ or $10$ and outdegrees is either $3$ or $7$?
Obviously, if we denote $x_2, x_{10}, y_3, y_7$ the number of vertices of indegrees $2$, $10$ and outdegrees $3$ and $7$ correspondingly, existence of such graph must imply the following equations:
$$
2x_2+10x_{10} = 3y_3+7y_7
$$
and of course, because the amount of vertices is $100$:
$$ x_2 + x_{10} = y_3 + y_7 = 100 $$
Using some papers and some pens I found some solutions, for example:
$$  x_2 = 38, x_{10} = 62, y_3 = 1, y_7 = 99 $$
and
$$ x_2 = 84, x_{10} = 16, y_3 = 93, y_7 =  7$$
But I couldn't construct a graph using these solutions, so I made a guess that such graph can't exist, but how to prove it?

We must have $x_2 + x_{10} = y_3+y_7 = 100$, no?

To not have loops there must be at least one vertex with outdegree $0$. Same with  indegree.

@ZoeAllen I think he forbid self-loops

@caduk Yes! I've edeted and recalculated some solutions, they also exist

@ZoeAllen I wanted to find a graph without self loops, but why it must have indegree 0 and outdegree 0?

Do reverse edges like $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ count as multiple edges for you?
If not, then I have found an example. Since you said "oriented graph" I am thinking these are not allowed

@dbal No, edges like $(i, j)$ and $(j, i)$ are not multiple, so we can have edges like from $1$ to $2$ and from $2$ to $1$. Oh, what's an example?

I managed to find an example without such reversed edges either. Will post as an answer.

Just as a notational thing, "oriented graph" typically refers to graphs without such "anti-directed edges"

Solutions for your pair of equations can be found using the theory of diophantine equations.
If you specify your two degree sequences (you specify for each vertex both its outdegree and indegree), you can decide their realizability using Fulkerson–Chen–Anstee theorem (this is the equivalent of Erdős–Gallai theorem, but for directed graphs). You can obtain explicit constructions using The Kleitman–Wang algorithms.
Here, you have the liberty to appary your indegree and outdegree as you wish.
With $(a_i)_{i=1...n}$ sorted in decreasing order and $(b_i)_{i=1...n}$ the two degree sequences, we need to verify for $1\leq k \leq n$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}\leq \sum _{i=1}^{k}\min(b_{i},k-1)+\sum _{i=k+1}^{n}\min(b_{i},k)$$
For a fixed $k$, if $b_i \leq k-1$, then both $\min(b_{i},k-1)$ and $\min(b_{i},k)$ are equal to $b_i$, so it does not matter on wich side they are, however, if $b_i\geq k$, we would prefer to put it in the left sum. So the best option is match the highest indegree with lowest indegree, second highest indegree with second lowest indegree on so on...
If we take your first example, we get the degree sequences $(10, ...  \textit{ (62 times) } ... 10, 2, ... \textit{ (38 times) } ... 2)$ and $(3, 7, ... \textit{ (99 times) } ... 7)$
It is sufficient to verify the equation only for the $k$ where $a_k > a_{k+1}$ (beside $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i$ which is true by construction) so we have only one inequality to check ($k=62$). We have  $\sum_{i=1}^{62}a_{i} = 620$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{62}\min(b_{i},61)+\sum _{i=k+1}^{n}\min(b_{i},62) = 3 + 7\times 99 = 696$, so there exist graphs satisfying these degrees. Again, we can construct some using the Kleitman–Wang algorithms.

I found an example with $x_2=87, x_{10}=13, y_3=99, y_7=1$. It has $2\cdot 87 + 10\cdot 13 = 304$ edges.
I'm not really sure the best way to communicate it. At the end of the post I will just list all the edges. I guess you can copy and paste this list to create a networkx graph in python.
To find the graph I first found (using python) all the solutions to the equations you listed (there were 50 such solutions). I had a hunch that a solution would be most easily found in a solution which corresponds to fewer edges, so I narrowed my search to those. The solution $x_2=87, x_{10}=13, y_3=99, y_7=1$ corrsponds to the fewest possible edges.
Then I used networkx directed_configuration_model to create a bunch of instances (maybe 10-20K)  until I found one that had no multiple edges and no self-loops. This gave me the solution which had "anti-directed pairs". I was then able to fix those anti-directed pairs by hand.
[(0, 56),
(0, 61),
(0, 93),
(1, 66),
(1, 88),
(1, 96),
(2, 23),
(2, 25),
(2, 87),
(3, 30),
(3, 87),
(3, 91),
(4, 19),
(4, 88),
(4, 89),
(5, 0),
(5, 87),
(5, 89),
(6, 85),
(6, 89),
(6, 97),
(7, 48),
(7, 73),
(7, 94),
(8, 13),
(8, 44),
(8, 50),
(9, 37),
(9, 91),
(9, 92),
(10, 67),
(10, 68),
(10, 83),
(11, 7),
(11, 68),
(11, 99),
(12, 24),
(12, 31),
(12, 95),
(13, 16),
(13, 42),
(13, 93),
(14, 10),
(14, 18),
(14, 54),
(15, 81),
(15, 88),
(15, 97),
(16, 19),
(16, 70),
(16, 96),
(17, 28),
(17, 75),
(17, 79),
(18, 8),
(18, 95),
(18, 99),
(19, 26),
(19, 41),
(19, 79),
(20, 11),
(20, 53),
(20, 88),
(21, 11),
(21, 93),
(21, 95),
(22, 16),
(22, 42),
(22, 96),
(23, 22),
(23, 93),
(23, 95),
(24, 45),
(24, 60),
(24, 99),
(25, 49),
(25, 87),
(25, 98),
(26, 50),
(26, 86),
(26, 88),
(27, 15),
(27, 41),
(27, 96),
(28, 48),
(28, 64),
(28, 76),
(29, 3),
(29, 47),
(29, 84),
(30, 9),
(30, 67),
(30, 91),
(31, 71),
(31, 87),
(31, 94),
(32, 4),
(32, 75),
(32, 86),
(33, 15),
(33, 94),
(33, 97),
(34, 74),
(34, 80),
(34, 93),
(35, 27),
(35, 90),
(35, 94),
(36, 35),
(36, 52),
(36, 58),
(37, 1),
(37, 17),
(37, 92),
(38, 70),
(38, 88),
(38, 98),
(39, 91),
(39, 97),
(39, 98),
(40, 32),
(40, 92),
(40, 94),
(41, 85),
(41, 87),
(41, 92),
(42, 24),
(42, 82),
(42, 92),
(43, 7),
(43, 65),
(43, 89),
(44, 5),
(44, 55),
(44, 90),
(45, 4),
(45, 54),
(45, 84),
(46, 1),
(46, 87),
(46, 89),
(47, 72),
(47, 91),
(47, 96),
(48, 2),
(48, 71),
(48, 96),
(49, 0),
(49, 35),
(49, 60),
(50, 32),
(50, 55),
(50, 94),
(51, 57),
(51, 93),
(51, 98),
(52, 37),
(52, 49),
(52, 99),
(53, 88),
(53, 92),
(53, 98),
(54, 6),
(54, 89),
(54, 90),
(55, 18),
(55, 83),
(55, 99),
(56, 81),
(56, 88),
(56, 93),
(57, 62),
(57, 92),
(57, 97),
(58, 8),
(58, 14),
(58, 69),
(59, 21),
(59, 94),
(59, 95),
(60, 28),
(60, 87),
(60, 91),
(61, 26),
(61, 31),
(61, 99),
(62, 33),
(62, 39),
(62, 92),
(63, 10),
(63, 20),
(63, 29),
(64, 33),
(64, 46),
(64, 69),
(65, 57),
(65, 62),
(65, 95),
(66, 77),
(66, 80),
(66, 91),
(67, 34),
(67, 90),
(67, 91),
(68, 27),
(68, 93),
(68, 99),
(69, 20),
(69, 46),
(69, 91),
(70, 72),
(70, 88),
(70, 89),
(71, 36),
(71, 78),
(71, 97),
(72, 34),
(72, 43),
(72, 99),
(73, 13),
(73, 30),
(73, 87),
(74, 9),
(74, 29),
(74, 91),
(75, 87),
(75, 92),
(75, 97),
(76, 14),
(76, 74),
(76, 89),
(77, 61),
(77, 96),
(77, 97),
(78, 43),
(78, 59),
(78, 95),
(79, 5),
(79, 23),
(79, 90),
(80, 39),
(80, 40),
(80, 65),
(81, 6),
(81, 45),
(81, 93),
(82, 94),
(82, 95),
(82, 97),
(83, 64),
(83, 94),
(83, 95),
(84, 58),
(84, 93),
(84, 98),
(85, 21),
(85, 63),
(85, 77),
(86, 52),
(86, 82),
(86, 96),
(87, 12),
(87, 17),
(87, 38),
(88, 51),
(88, 76),
(88, 98),
(89, 2),
(89, 53),
(89, 98),
(90, 59),
(90, 63),
(90, 99),
(91, 12),
(91, 51),
(91, 90),
(92, 89),
(92, 90),
(92, 94),
(93, 36),
(93, 66),
(93, 96),
(94, 44),
(94, 90),
(94, 98),
(95, 25),
(95, 89),
(95, 90),
(96, 3),
(96, 95),
(96, 97),
(97, 56),
(97, 90),
(97, 99),
(98, 40),
(98, 47),
(98, 96),
(99, 22),
(99, 38),
(99, 73),
(99, 78),
(99, 88),
(99, 92),
(99, 98)]
